# Bus times from Anuradhapura to Kandy?

Tags: public-transport, buses, sri-lanka

What time do air conditioned buses run from Anuradhapura to Kandy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My parents live in Anuradhapura and I live in Kandy, and I make this trip up and down at least once a month.

The earliest Intercity from A/pura to Kandy is at 4.30-5 AM from A/pura. Reaches Kandy at about 7.30AM, depends on the traffic.

The last bus departs at 7.30PM, reaches Kandy at 9.30-10PM but you will not find any other buses in A6 road (Kandy to Mahiyangana road which has many tourist hotels), Three-wheelers are available but expect to pay a slightly higher price. 
For A1 (Kandy to Colombo), you will find a bus even at the mid-night.

Kandy to A/pura buses are available every 30 mins from 6.30 AM to 6.45 PM.

You can call +94252225257 (A/pura bus depot) and ask them if they have buses available.

Also, there are 2 routes in between A/pura and Kandy. 
42 and 43. 
A/C buses are only available in 43 because the 42 is a little bumpy road near A/pura. 
Buses in 42 route, IMO, are very uncomfortable compared to 43's.

Comment: You probably meant 4.30AM, didn't you?

Comment: @LouisHuppenbauer yes 4.30 AM. Sorry. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Now there are buses in every 20 minutes from 5.15am to 5pm from kandy.from a,pura 4.45am to 5.15 pm.there normal 3 buses in route 43 and other buses in route 42.most effective normal bus i have seen is gampola-anuradhpura ctb bus from a.pura depot.if u wish to take it from gampola 12.30pm,kandy 2pm reach a,pura at 5.45-6.10pm.i dont know the time from a,pura.

Answer (score 0):

A local told me that the private air conditioned buses run every 15 minutes during the day. So there is no published schedule as far as I could see.